# Checking if the VPN is still connected and reconnect if needed

Tags: powershell, vpn

I have a script written in powershell that connects to a VPN
Now i want to make it reconnect to the VPN if it is disconnected. Can i do that with what i have now ?

I am new to PowerShell so please bear with me.

```
#Source www.cze.cz
#This script is tested with "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client version 3.0.5080"
#Please change following variables

#IP address or host name of cisco vpn
[string]$CiscoVPNHost = "ip address"
[string]$Login = "user"
[string]$Password = "pass"

#Please check if file exists on following paths
[string]$vpncliAbsolutePath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe'
[string]$vpnuiAbsolutePath  = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe'

#****************************************************************************
#**** Please do not modify code below unless you know what you are doing ****
#****************************************************************************

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms -ErrorAction Stop

#Set foreground window function
#This function is called in VPNConnect
Add-Type @'
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Win {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
'@ -ErrorAction Stop

#quickly start VPN
#This function is called later in the code
Function VPNConnect()
{
    Start-Process -FilePath $vpncliAbsolutePath -ArgumentList "connect $CiscoVPNHost"
    $counter = 0; $h = 0;
    while($counter++ -lt 1000 -and $h -eq 0)
    {
        sleep -m 10
        $h = (Get-Process vpncli).MainWindowHandle
    }
    #if it takes more than 10 seconds then display message
    if($h -eq 0){echo "Could not start VPNUI it takes too long."}
    else{[void] [Win]::SetForegroundWindow($h)}
}

#Terminate all vpnui processes.
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {if($_.ProcessName.ToLower() -eq "vpnui")
{$Id = $_.Id; Stop-Process $Id; echo "Process vpnui with id: $Id was stopped"}}
#Terminate all vpncli processes.
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {if($_.ProcessName.ToLower() -eq "vpncli")
{$Id = $_.Id; Stop-Process $Id; echo "Process vpncli with id: $Id was stopped"}}


#Disconnect from VPN
echo "Trying to terminate remaining vpn connections"
start-Process -FilePath $vpncliAbsolutePath -ArgumentList 'disconnect' -wait
#Connect to VPN
echo "Connecting to VPN address '$CiscoVPNHost' as user '$Login'."
VPNConnect

#Write login and password
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Login{Enter}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Password{Enter}")

#Start vpnui
start-Process -FilePath $vpnuiAbsolutePath
#Wait for keydown`enter code here`
echo "Press any key to continue ..."
try{$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")}catch{}
```

Comment: What services are at the other end of the vpn?  (eg, web server, ftp server, file server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you code in a function like this:

```
function Reconnect-VPN {

    #Source www.cze.cz
    #This script is tested with "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client version 3.0.5080"
    #Please change following variables

    #IP address or host name of cisco vpn
    [string]$CiscoVPNHost = "ip address"
    [string]$Login = "user"
    [string]$Password = "pass"

    #Please check if file exists on following paths
    [string]$vpncliAbsolutePath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe'
    [string]$vpnuiAbsolutePath  = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe'

    #****************************************************************************
    #**** Please do not modify code below unless you know what you are doing ****
    #****************************************************************************

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms -ErrorAction Stop

    #Set foreground window function
    #This function is called in VPNConnect
    Add-Type @'
      using System;
      using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
      public class Win {
         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
         public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
      }
    '@ -ErrorAction Stop

    #quickly start VPN
    #This function is called later in the code
    Function VPNConnect()
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath $vpncliAbsolutePath -ArgumentList "connect $CiscoVPNHost"
        $counter = 0; $h = 0;
        while($counter++ -lt 1000 -and $h -eq 0)
        {
            sleep -m 10
            $h = (Get-Process vpncli).MainWindowHandle
        }
        #if it takes more than 10 seconds then display message
        if($h -eq 0){echo "Could not start VPNUI it takes too long."}
        else{[void] [Win]::SetForegroundWindow($h)}
    }

    #Terminate all vpnui processes.
    Get-Process | ForEach-Object {if($_.ProcessName.ToLower() -eq "vpnui")
    {$Id = $_.Id; Stop-Process $Id; echo "Process vpnui with id: $Id was stopped"}}
    #Terminate all vpncli processes.
    Get-Process | ForEach-Object {if($_.ProcessName.ToLower() -eq "vpncli")
    {$Id = $_.Id; Stop-Process $Id; echo "Process vpncli with id: $Id was stopped"}}


    #Disconnect from VPN
    echo "Trying to terminate remaining vpn connections"
    start-Process -FilePath $vpncliAbsolutePath -ArgumentList 'disconnect' -wait
    #Connect to VPN
    echo "Connecting to VPN address '$CiscoVPNHost' as user '$Login'."
    VPNConnect

    #Write login and password
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Login{Enter}")
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Password{Enter}")

    #Start vpnui
    start-Process -FilePath $vpnuiAbsolutePath
    #Wait for keydown`enter code here`
    echo "Press any key to continue ..."
    try{$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")}catch{}
}
```

Then, choose an IP address that is only reachable when VPN is connected, and ping it. If ping fails, run the `Reconnect-VPN` function:

```
$testIP = "10.10.10.10"

if(-not (Test-Connection $testIP)) {
    Reconnect-VPN
}
```